# Does SFSpeechRecognizer contextualStrings require internet to work?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using on-device speech-to-text in my app, and I was hoping to use contextualStrings to help it recognize some more niche vocabulary. However, it never recognizes any of the words. I am following all of the guidelines they outline [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech/sfspeechrecognitionrequest/1649391-contextualstrings), but they never seem to be recognized when I  have `requiresOnDeviceRecognition` set to true. They do get recognized when I set `requiresOnDeviceRecognition` to false, however. Is it because the Speech-to-Text engine is better with it off? Or does `contextualString` require the internet to work? I couldn't find any documentation saying it needs internet.

Example:

```
...
private let contextualStrings = ["hipaa", "cologuard"]
recognitionRequest.contextualStrings = contextualStrings
```

**Hipaa** always becomes **hyppa** for some reason (which isn't even a word on the system vocabulary?)

Interestingly, if I were to say "HIPAA violation" does HIPAA actually get recognized by the on-device speech-to-text engine. This seems to be only time it ever works

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour. Furthermore it just seems to work only for en_US. Did you find solution ?

Comment: I believe that for `contextualString` to work, you have to have `requiresOnDeviceRecognition` set to false. There would be a way to validate it through wireshark but I never had the desire to prove it. The documentation doesn't mention this behavior though, which is lame since I wasted a lot of time debugging.